# Not able to get current location latitude and longitude in android

Tags: android, google-maps

I am new in android and i want to fetch my current location longitude and latitude and i have used this code to fetch my latitude and longitude and i cannot see the results in my logcat and i have also moved the google-services.json file app/ and intialised the mGoogleApiClient and mLastLocation and i am not getting any error then why i am not able to see the latitude and longitude.Please help me and thanks in advance
here is the complete code of my app https://github.com/akashmalla07/GoogleMap
please have a look if anyone can help me

Here is the code of Mapsactivity

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

         private GoogleMap mMap; 
         AppLocationService appLocationService;
         GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
         private Location mLastLocation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
       setUpMapIfNeeded();

    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (mMap == null) {
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            if (mMap != null) {
                displayLocation();
            }
        }
    }

    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            Log.d("result", latitude + ", " + longitude);

        } else {

          Log.d("result3","(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is 
          enabled on the device)");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }
}
```

And these are the imports

```
  import android.location.Location;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
  import android.util.Log;

  import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult; 
  import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
  import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
  import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
  import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
```

Updated code-------------------------------------------

```
      public class MapsActivity extends Activity implements 
       GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;
private GoogleMap mMap;
AppLocationService appLocationService;
GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Location mLastLocation;

private TextView lblLocation;
private Button btnShowLocation, btnStartLocationUpdates;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    lblLocation = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblLocation);
    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);
    btnStartLocationUpdates = (Button) 
      findViewById(R.id.btnLocationUpdates);

    if (checkPlayServices()) {

        // Building the GoogleApi client
        buildGoogleApiClient();

      }

    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            displayLocation();
            Log.d("clicked","yes");
        }
    });

}
protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
}
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    checkPlayServices();

}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

}
@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
            + result.getErrorCode());
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

    displayLocation();


}



private void displayLocation() {
   Log.d("after","clicked");
    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        lblLocation.setText(latitude + ", " + longitude);
        Log.d("lat",String.valueOf(latitude));

    } else {
        Log.d("lat","No lat");

        lblLocation
                .setText("(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device)");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}
```

}

Comment: Before posting your question you have to take a look in simular questions. Take a look here [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28877835/android-google-maps-v2-current-position-latitude-longitude-nullpointerexception). you'll find more simular solutions.

Comment: Could you also show what **imports** are their in your class. Or make sure you have Location is enabled in your real device from Settings.

Comment: @jaydroider in my mobile device location is enabled and i have edited the question where u can see the imports

Comment: If you are using API 23, then you need to enable permission once you install the app.

Comment: Or check whether the location is enabled by manually goes to Setting---> Location Access

Comment: @ParamaSudha i didnot get you can you please elaborate

Comment: Refer this http://kiddyandroid.blogspot.in/2016/04/getting-latitude-longitude-while.html

Comment: http://www.tutorialsbuzz.com/2016/02/Android-show-Current-Location-On-GoogleMap-Animation.html

Comment: What is the target API Level?

Comment: @ParamaSudha target is 23

Comment: May be you need to connect `GoogleApiClient` `onStart` of `Activity`. Your imports looks okay.

Comment: @jaydroider after following your answers and other tutorials i changed my code and still i am not getting my latitude and please have a look at my new code in my edited post inserted at the last as **updated code-----**

Comment: The `getLastLocation()` may well return null if there's no "last location" available. The method call does not determine the location it only returns it if it's known. And it's only known if some other app has requested a location update recently or since the phone was booted up. (I don't know what's the exact behaviour.) And in any case the "last location" might not even be up-to-date even if it's available. Maybe the documentation should be clearer on this as often people use `getLastLocation()` and then complain that they "can not the get location".

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thank you for sharing your knowledge but can you please tell me what should i write instead of 'getLastLocation()' to get my current location latitude and longitude

Comment: You could request location updates [as instructed in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html). If you do not need constant location updates then you can of course stop them as soon as you receive the current location.

Answer (score 0):

your forgot to call  mGoogleApiClient.connect();

```
    public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

     private GoogleMap mMap; 
     AppLocationService appLocationService;
     GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
     private Location mLastLocation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks((GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks) this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener((GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener) this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();

 mGoogleApiClient.connect();

}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) 
        getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            displayLocation();
        }
    }
}

private void displayLocation() {

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

        Log.d("result", latitude + ", " + longitude);

    } else {

      Log.d("result3","(Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is 
      enabled on the device)");
    }
}

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
          mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
   setUpMapIfNeeded();
}

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

}

@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

}
}
```

I have edited your code. See if this work.

Comment: **D/result3﹕ Couldn't get the location. Make sure location is enabled on the device** this is want i am getting in my logcat

Comment: please check whether  GoogleApiClient is connected or not and also location settings in your mobile settings are enabled

Comment: my location in setting is enabled and can u tell me how to check whether GoogleApiClient is connected or not?

Comment: mGoogleApiClient.isConnected();

Comment: after following your answers and other tutorials i changed my code and still i am not getting my latitude and please have a look at my new code in my edited post inserted at the last as **updated code-----**

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 mistakes in your code

You are not connected to `GoogleApiclient`, so call `mgoogleApiclient.connect` just after you build it using builder.

Call your `displayLocation()` method in `onConnected()` callback method. As, this is the success callback of `GoogleApiClient`, which means you are now connected to the client and can get your location.

Also, You can get location without registering any **GoogleApikey** until you are not using `Maps` or `Places` Api in your app.

Comment: after following your answer and some other tutorials i changed my code and still i am not getting my latitude and this time my mobile location is also enabled and you can see the new code in my edited post **updated code ------**

Comment: Can u tell me any other way to fetch the current latitud and longitude

Comment: Try to debug your code, is GoogleApiClient connected?